# create an Android Scroll List programmatically

Tags: java, android, hashmap, iteration

Coming from a web dev background, what I'm looking for should be quite simple. I have pulled all the contacts from the android phone.

Their names and numbers are in a HashMap called contacts (number = key) I'm iterating through them and I'm looking to create a list of them for the user to see. The key (the phone number) must be available there but not be seen, and The List must scroll. So something like the `<option value="phone">Name</option>` would be perfect. I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: something like google http://www.learn-android.com/2009/12/05/lots-of-lists-1-simple/

Answer (score 1):

Use an adapter to inflate the list into ListView.

Like:

```
public class SimpleListView extends ListActivity {

private String[] lv_arr = {};
private ListView mainListView = null;
final String SETTING_TODOLIST = "todolist";

private ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple);


    // Prepare an ArrayList of todo items
    ArrayList<String> listTODO = [INSERT THE VALUES FROM THE CONTACTS HERE];

    this.mainListView = getListView();

    // Bind the data with the list
    lv_arr = listTODO.toArray(new String[0]);
    mainListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SimpleListView.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, lv_arr));

}
```

}

You also need a layout:
simple.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mainListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/size"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:horizontalSpacing="15dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:numColumns="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```